# How to compile the source code for gnu typist?

Tags: compiling

I am new ubuntu user and try to install [gnu typist](http://www.gnu.org/software/gtypist/).
I need to compile the source code to run the app.
According to documentation i need c compiler to compile the source code.

I don't have idea how to compile the source code and start using the app on ubuntu/linux.

Please help me to migrate on ubuntu/linux from windows?

Comment: see similar post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1026/how-to-compile-source-code-from-a-tarball

Comment: please edit your question to clarify that you want to install Gnu Typist rather than asking for general compiling from source to avoid duplicate questions ;)

Comment: @Takkat - I want to install Gnu Typist; but also i want to learn whole compilation process as well.

Comment: That has already been answered here: [How to compile source code from a tarball?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1026/how-to-compile-source-code-from-a-tarball)

Comment: how to compile has been answered before, see aneeshep's and Marco's comments. For an easy howto see the URL to Ubuntu documentation I gave you. There you will also find links for further reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you *do* want to compile it for any reason, download it and do the following:

```
cd Downloads/
tar -xvf gtypist-2.8.3.tar.gz 
cd gtypist-2.8.3/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The last three lines are the important bit, the first three are just changing to the directory where it's been downloaded to, unpacking the archive and changing to the directory where it's been unpacked to.

Please, before you do, carefully read the INSTALL file that comes with the program, and see if you needn't do something different. You should in any case, if you don't have a very good  reason not to, **[install it from the Repositories](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gtypist)** as Takkat suggests.

Answer (score 2):

For a new Ubuntu user there usually is no need to compile applications from source. However this [can be done](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo).

In your case I would strongly recommend you install [Gnu Typist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/maverick/gtypist) (or gtypist which is the same) through the [software center](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter) or [synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto).