# How to install a tar.bz2 package

Tags: installation, package-management, tar

How can I install a tarbz2 package. Example: I have downloaded firefox 8 tar.bz2 . I want to know a general method for installation of tar.bz2 package.

Comment: see this answer man.. http://askubuntu.com/q/1026/34751

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, to install a `tar.bz2` (or `.tar`, or `.tar.gz`, or `tar.xz`, or, rarely, `.tar.Z`), see [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo). Please note that the specific flag to indicate to the `tar` command that you want to extract (or create) a bz2-compressed archive is `j`.

However, you should probably not install Firefox 8 from upstream sources, as you seem to be trying to do. That is not the best way to get it, other programs that depend on it would not necessarily know that it was installed, you would not benefit from changes made specifically for Ubuntu (if any), and you would not automatically receive updates (including security updates)--instead, when a new version comes out, you would have to manually compile and install that version.

Instead, you should probably update to Firefox in the recommended way for Ubuntu:

- [How do I install the latest stable version of Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox)