# Can't install tar.bz2 file due to "no such file or directory" error

Tags: installation, command-line, tar

I've been trying compile mdk3-v6 but I run into errors.

Started off by trying `sudo apt-get install` that didn't work. 
Downloaded from another source and tried `tar -xjf mdk3-v6.tar.bz2`

Keep getting `No such file directory error`. Also downloaded all the 32bit support since I'm running 64bit & have the build essentials and all that. 
Tried using `-xzf` instead of `-xjf` and other tasks. Changed Makefile to `-pthread`.
I think I've tried everything.

If someone could help me out I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/82497/how-to-install-a-tar-bz2-package?rq=1 (good compile link in the answer to that question)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're in your home directory but your file probably downloaded in the Downloads directory or something similar.

You need to be in the same directory as the file or specify by doing `tar xjf Downloads/blah.tar.bz2`

A good trick I use instead of typing it all out is just type in the first few keys and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the shell will autocomplete the filename for you. If you do that and the file doesn't complete, you know you're in the wrong directory.

Comment: I tried that and I got the same type of message. 

 tar -xjf Downloads/mdk3-v6.tar.bz2
tar (child): Downloads/mdk3-v6.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Could it be that I'm missing bzip2 somehow?

Comment: You need to put where you actually saved the file as your path.