# How to install package that was downloaded as source files

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compile source code from a tarball?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026/how-to-compile-source-code-from-a-tarball)

Please suggest me as step-by-step process.
I thinkthat first of all,I have to decompress and compile them but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Are you asking to compile packages from tarballs (*.tar)?

Comment: What source file? There is no readme or install.txt inside it?

Comment: You have to use dpkg and dpkg-source,  however I have done it very long time ago and can't remember right now step by step instuctions. However googling those commands would be much help I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do...

Decompress the tra/gzip file

Go into the decompressed directory

Look for files like: README or INSTALL. These files usually contains the instructions to install the source code.

If no such instructions are mentioned then follow these steps:

./configute
./make
./install

This should help you.