# Log SSH activity

Tags: ssh, log

All, I have an Ubuntu host that accepts SSH connections.  How can I log all commands that are run on a specific account that logs in via SSH?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can make sshd use a logging shell like [rootsh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/)?

Comment: how do you install rootsh on Ubuntu

Comment: @Lexicon: AFAIK there's no already-compiled deb package available, just a source archive. Installing an application from source is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1026/how-to-compile-source-code-from-a-tarball), for example. The INSTALL file located in the source archive describes the different config options you can set before compiling it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with snoopy.
After you install it, will logs all input command that calls execve to syslog.
you'll only find it in the repos for hardy and precise.

You can install it from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/snoopy/).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think SSHD logs commands while the user is logged in.

you can check who logged in by checking

`/var/log/auth.log`

and cross reference it to their history

`/home/sshuser/.bash_history`

history will have commands local or remote though.

Comment: auth.log contains session opened and closed info but not commands that were ran while logged in.  .Bash_history only show local commands, nothing through the ssh session (at least from what I can tell).

Comment: ~/.bash_history will not work as the user can alter the file.

Comment: .bash_history is not showing what happens via ssh.

Comment: What is in `.bash_history` depends on how you've configured it. It may show anything from a mix of every concurrent shell session to nothing at all. (I `export HISTFILE=''` in my `.bashrc` on all systems to turn off recording history for security reasons, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and wrote the tool [log-user-session](https://github.com/open-ch/log-user-session) which stores all shell output into a root-only accessible session log file. It can be enabled via forced command on sshd_conf or ~/.ssh/authorized keys (see [documentation](https://github.com/open-ch/log-user-session/blob/develop/doc/log-user-session.pod)).