# logging ssh clients session

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Log SSH activity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112686/log-ssh-activity)

I need to implement a secure server to be the only source for connecting to routers and switches in the lan. 
The only task that that is getting me trouble to solve is the requirement to log all the users actions in the server (and the routers).

I've trying with ttysnoop, but can't autostart the log to file when a user log in.

Ther is a way to accomplish this?

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Duplicate: [Log SSH activity](http://askubuntu.com/q/112686/20661) - question should get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe rootsh could work. http://www.hackersgarage.com/how-to-track-linux-shell-users-activity.html

Comment: I'll give it a try, sounds like the perfect soluction.. thank you!!!