# Recent system logins

Tags: login, logging

How would I be able to find logs of recent login or usage activity on my desktop? Is there a script or place in Ubuntu that holds data that tells you of recent logins from user, guest, or remote.

Comment: You could combine commands w and who and unhide within a new bash-script ?
Or is this too few ?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the best tool is the command last

```
last
```

You can pipe the output to less

```
last | less
```

or a file and then search the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can show login history of user-accounts as following:

Go to **System Settings > User Accounts** and click on **History** button

[image: login-history]

[image: history-screen]

---

From **Command-line** Open terminal and type: [**`last`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/last.1.html)

```
Usage: last [-num | -n num] [-f file] [-t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS] [-R] [-adioxFw] [username..] [tty..]
```

Ex: `last pandya` for activity of user=pandya

For more information see `man last`

> last, lastb - show listing of last logged in users
>
> **FILES:**
> /var/log/wtmp
> /var/log/btmp

---

**Also Visit**:[how-can-i-track-who-sshes-into-my-linux-machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26671/how-can-i-track-who-sshes-into-my-linux-machine) & [Log SSH activity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112686/log-ssh-activity)

Answer (score 0):

The file /var/log/auth.log is most likely what you are looking for. The messages look like the following for local logins:

```
Jun  3 21:09:57 johnserver login[1810]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user johndoe
```

and like so for remote logins:

```
Jun  3 21:16:53 johnserver sshd[949]: Accepted password for johndoe from 127.0.0.1 port 54425 ssh2
```

where johnserver is the hostname and johndoe is the username.

I am sorry that I do not have any knowledge on how guest logins are displayed/conveyed.