# How to record putty session?

Tags: putty

I have Ubuntu server and we are using putty to take remote session  from Windows. I want to record the activity which was done by putty session by any user. Is it possible? If yes then how?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231877/saving-the-putty-session-logging

Comment: Or https://askubuntu.com/questions/112686/log-ssh-activity