# How do I compile lbflow 1.1?

Tags: gcc, install-from-source, make, g++

After using "sh ./configure" command, I encountered another error during [lbflow package](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=19657&d=1275976883) installation (a scientific one).

The sequence of operations is here with error:

```
./configure --disable-gts

sudo make

[sudo] password for alireza:
make all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/alireza/lbflow-1.1'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/alireza/lbflow-1.1/src'
source='lbflow.cpp' object='lbflow-lbflow.o' libtool=no \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/bash ../depcomp \
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -c -o lbflow-lbflow.o `test -f 'lbflow.cpp' || echo    './'`lbflow.cpp
**../depcomp: line 432: exec: g++: not found**
**make[2]: *** [lbflow-lbflow.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/alireza/lbflow-1.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alireza/lbflow-1.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2**
```

Do you have any idea to troubleshoot this problem?

(And please notice that i have installed both g++ and gcc. it says g++: not found, but i have installed g++ from Ubuntu Software Center!)

Comment: Before trying to troubleshoot this, based on your previous thread I strongly suggest you delete the folder and unpack it again from the tar.gz file in your /home directory - it is possible other file permissions got messed up when you originally unpacked it on an external drive and then moved it.

Comment: Please include a link to the piece of software in your question. Then we (including myself) can try to build the software as well to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `sed -n -e 432p ../depcomp` and `which g++`.

Comment: @steeldriver i did it. the ./configure worked this time, but the make error is still present.

Comment: @gertvdijk
Here's the package: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=19657&d=1275976883

Comment: @chaos
"sed..." command output:sed: can't read ../depcomp: No such file or directory. And "which g++" command returned no output

Comment: @Ali.A This piece of software appears to be extremely old. It's also not open source and only available via the original website for academic purposes with an interesting note. http://www.dur.ac.uk/ed.llewellin/lbflow/downloads.htm I suggest to invest your time in finding an alternative.

Comment: @gertvdijk, dear friend, the package is not old, it IS open source for academic use, and besides i got it from the owner of package: Dr. Ed Llevellin, through a mail that he sent to me :)

Comment: Well, all source is from 2005-2008, completely unmaintained and is not compatible with GCC 4.3 and up. <-- there's your answer. Use an older compiler, because this software relies on *very old* behaviour of compilers. See also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1500374

Comment: @gertvdijik I don't think so. When the owner sent the email just 4 days ago, it means that he takes care of hic package. but i do respect to your reply. thanx anyway

Comment: Please don't add "solved" in the titles. Accepted answers are what mark question as answered. This is not a forum, you mustn't edit titles just to mark a question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `g++` is installed with `dpkg --list | grep g++`. In my case:

```
ii  g++                                       4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5                                    GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-4.6                                   4.6.3-1ubuntu5                                      GNU C++ compiler
```

`ii` stands for installed. Then check with `which g++`, it should output something like this:

```
/usr/bin/g++
```

If the which command outputs nothing it is not installed or the patch where the binary is stored is not in your `$PATH` variable.

To install `g++` compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Finally the last check whould be `g++ --version`, in my case:

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If that all works everything is fine with your compiler. After `g++` is installed and available retry your ./configure and make commands. Let me know if it works.

**EDIT Compilation errors:**

So I got it. I organized the package you try to compile form another forum and compiled it myself. The problem is, gcc has cleaned up header dependencies, so with a gcc version >=4.3 some code isn't compiling anymore. See http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/porting_to.html for what to include to avoid compile errors. In your folder where you executed the ./configure and make command, open the file `src/parser.h` file and add this lines to the include statements at line 15 under `#include <iostream>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
```

Then the run the make command again. It should not fail. In my test is was a success.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.

the 'code' dpkg --list | grep g++ 'code' returns:
'code' 
ii  g++-4.6              4.6.3-1ubuntu5
GNU C++ compiler
'code'

The 'code' which g++ 'code' did not return any outputs. so i used the 'code' sudo apt-get install build-essential 'code' command. Yes. it installed the compiler. But i still encounter the error.

Comment: If the error `exec: g++: not found` still encounters then your compiler isn't installed correctly yet. What's the output of the last check `g++ --version`?

Comment: then what should i do now?

`g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice that `exec: g++: not found` message perished. But this is the error which is now appered:
`make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/alireza/lbflow-1.1'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/alireza/lbflow-1.1/src'
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..        -g -O2 -MT lbflow-lbflow.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/lbflow-lbflow.Tpo" -c -o lbflow-lbflow.o `test -f 'lbflow.cpp' || echo './'`lbflow.cpp; \
 then mv -f ".deps/lbflow-lbflow.Tpo" ".deps/lbflow-lbflow.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/lbflow-lbflow.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
`

Comment: ...continued
`In file included from lbflow.cpp:27:0:
parser.h:67:5: error: ‘uint’ does not name a type
make[2]: *** [lbflow-lbflow.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/alireza/lbflow-1.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alireza/lbflow-1.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: @Ali.A I've already tried to indicate all that in my comment to your question. This is the GCC 4.3+ incompatibility I was talking about.

Comment: @qertvdijk
You are right. i lost your comment and now i saw the link you left. yes it seems it's incompatibility issue. Then where can i find a lower version of gcc?
I searched ubuntu software packages but i didn't find any? what do you recommend to do?

Comment: @AliA: see my updated answer.

Comment: @chaos god bless you. I'm really appreciated by your help and the help of qertvdijk and steeldriver and...
I will try it and will let you know the results soon tomorrow.

Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Dear @chaos it worked! I'm fully appreciated :)