# Compiling R - configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs while installing R-3.0.0

Tags: 12.04, compiling, r

**Compiling R**

```
root@rani:/media/626CAD/androidnetbeans/R-3.0.0# sudo bash ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
loading site script './config.site'
loading build-specific script './config.site'
checking for pwd... /bin/pwd
checking whether builddir is srcdir... yes
checking for working aclocal... found
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake... found
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for which... /usr/bin/which
checking for less... /usr/bin/less
checking for gtar... no
checking for gnutar... no
checking for tar... /bin/tar
checking for tex... no
checking for pdftex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
checking for pdflatex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
checking for makeindex... no
checking for makeinfo... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
checking for texi2dvi... no
checking for kpsewhich... no
checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
checking for gzip... /bin/gzip
checking for bzip2... /bin/bzip2
checking for firefox... /usr/bin/firefox
using default browser ... /usr/bin/firefox
checking for acroread... no
checking for acroread4... no
checking for xdg-open... /usr/bin/xdg-open
checking for notangle... false
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/media/626CAD/androidnetbeans/R-3.0.0':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

This occurs when I try to install R 3.0.

**What shall I do?**

Comment: Run 'which gcc' and  'gcc --version' and share with us. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : Cannot run C compiled programs. if you meant to cross compile use --host' Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360329/error-cannot-run-c-compiled-programs-if-you-meant-to-cross-compile-use-host)

Comment: $which gcc give me :      /usr/bin/gcc                                                                           $ gcc --version give me:gcc-4.6.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
  Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is     NO  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A   PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Answer (score -2):

Usually, after compiling a C file it creates an executable file with .exe extension which is not supported in any of the Linux flavours. Try creating an output file. Something like a.out, ie with .out extension. It might help.